# Omission of ‘that is’ in English sentence

Tags: relative-clauses

In the sentence:
“it is a culture very comfortable with silence”

The “that” and “is” is omitted, anyone know what this is called or why it happens?

Comment: If you want to you can pad the sentence with unnecessary words so that it reads "it is a culture that is very comfortable with silence". Is that what your asking about? Do you think the wordier version is better somehow?

Comment: Perhaps not a duplicate, but this may be relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140207/omitting-that-is-that-are-and-its-their

Comment: Nothing has been omitted; it's just a different kind of modifier of "culture". "Very comfortable with silence" is an adjective phrase, while "that is very comfortable with silence" is a relative clause. It's a free choice as to which one you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called ellipsis, and as a previous commenter has said, it's another way of modifying the noun. Ellipsis is used when there is no risk of the subject being confused (ie the subject stays the same) in order to make the phrase more elegant and to avoid redundancy.